# How to separate dev and dist script instructions in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I created **npm package** (ng-wig) and have inside my **package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/bower install && ./node_modules/.bin/grunt install"
},
```

so I want to run **bower** and **grunt** via `npm install` for my development purposes,

but how could I prevent this action for consumers of my package?

Is it only one way - to remove postinstall and do it each time manually for development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't add any dev related install step in the standard `npm install` (i.e. your postinstall hook).

You might prefer adding a "Contribute" section in your README, with the sub-section "install" where you specify the scripts to run.

Moreover, your module is correctly published on bower (the entry points are specified in the `main`of the `bower.json`) - but you didn't do the same for npm (specifying `main` or `files` in the `package.json`), which means that when you `npm install ng-wig` then `require('ng-wig')`, you get nothing.